# Zebra Printer - Missing Always use Driver Settings

Tags: printer, network-printer, windows-server-2016, crystal-reports, zebra-printer

We have multiple zebra label printers on a server for printing Crystal Reports. We have some printers that are using a larger 4 x 6 label vs the normal 4 x 3.

On the older printers (GK420D) I was able to get this working by selecting "Always use drivers settings" in the "Override Application Default Settings" area in the printer properties under the "Printer Settings" tab. If this wasn't selected the label wouldn't print in the correct orientation to fit everything into the label.

The newer printer (ZD621) does not have a "Printer Settings" tab in the properties and I cannot see an option to use driver settings anywhere else. So when I set the printer to print in landscape it ignores this.

Is there any other way to override the application default settings?

Comment: What server, and how are they connected? USB or network?

Comment: Windows server 2016 and they are network connected

Comment: I have this working currently by using the older driver for the GK420D on the newer printer. Shame this option isn't available on the newer drivers

Comment: You should contact Zebra Support.

Comment: can you uninstall the drivers, then reinstall as admin via right click, run as administrator?